# Using Erubis 2.6.2 with Rails 2.2.2 is incompatible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conflict, erubis

Supposedly installing [erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) is as simple as:

```
gem install erubis

# And in environment.rb:
require 'erubis/helpers/rails_helper'
```

But I haven't found this to be so.  Note that there are no evident errors in my code; it runs just fine and dandy with ERB.

1. Where do I put this line?  Directly after the `boot.rb` inclusion it fails to start the server, and at the end of the file I get an unexpected nil object error (nil.controller).  Where is best?
2. Are there known conflicts with the given versions?
3. Are there any workarounds I can utilize to get erubis functioning?

Comment: Erubis 2.6.4 has support for Rails 2.2 -- it just came out recently.

Answer (score 1):

1. Either put it on the bottom or environment.rb, or put it in an initializer (config/initializers/anything.rb). When you put it before the Rails::Initializer block, the rails environment hasn't fully loaded yet, and erubis/helpers/rails_helpers seems to assume a fully loaded Rails environment.
2. I have never used erubis, so I can't answer that.
3. Workarounds? See #1, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, but there's still that pesky nil object error to get rid of. :/

Comment: Impossible to tell what's causing this without seeing a full stack trace, and any relevant custom code the stack trace points to.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is broken:

http://kleinptr.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/erubis-and-rails-222/

and they're working on a fix:

http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/328613

Comment: Indeed it is broken, but I've since gone to HAML without looking back.  But thanks for the answer, someone else may find it helpful.  :)

Comment: Since then Erubis 2.6.4 has come out, with support for Rails 2.2 and 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Erubis (2.6.4) and  Rails 2.2 (and 2.3) are still not compatible.  The main issue is that the generated ruby code from Erubis uses "_buf" as the buffer variable and Rails 2.2 and 2.3 require "@output_buffer" to be used.

The reason for "@output_buffer" to be used is that ActionView helpers like CaptureHelper are designed around "@output_buffer" being the primary buffer in the generated code.

I have created a gem called [elkinsware-erubis_rails_helper](http://github.com/elkinsware/erubis_rails_helper/tree/master) that fixes these issues and allows Erubis and Rails 2.3 (for sure but it should work for 2.2).

In your environment.rb file add:

```
 config.gem 'erubis' , :version => '2.6.4'
 config.gem 'elkinsware-erubis_rails_helper', :lib => 'erubis_rails_helper', :source => 'http://gems.github.com'
```

And then you can add a config/initializers/erubis_config.rb where you can adjust the Erubis/Rails options.

```
 #Erubis::Helpers::RailsHelper.engine_class = Erubis::Eruby # or Erubis::FastEruby
 #Erubis::Helpers::RailsHelper.init_properties = {}
 #Erubis::Helpers::RailsHelper.show_src = false
 #Erubis::Helpers::RailsHelper.preprocessing = true
```

The source is at http://github.com/elkinsware/erubis_rails_helper/tree/master

Let me know if you have any issues with the gem.

Comment: Any ideas on how to make it work with concat? I've tried your gem but that isn't helping, see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850398/erubis-block-helper-throwing-error-with-concat