# Erubis block helper throwing error with concat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers, erubis

I have a couple of block helpers, here's a simple example of what I'm doing:

```
def wrap_foo foo, &block
    data = capture(&block)

    content = "
      <div class=\"foo\" id=\"#{foo}\">
        #{data}
      </div>"
    concat( content )
end
```

I'm just trying out erubis and it's giving me the following error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<
```

Removing the call to `concat` removes the error but ends up with my wrapper not being rendered

Using:

- Rails 2.3.5
- Erubis 2.6.5
- And tried [this gem](http://github.com/elkinsware/erubis%5Frails%5Fhelper/tree/master) that helps Erubis (though 2.6.4) and Rails 2.3 play better together

Comment: I have run into a similar problem using Formtastic and Erubis on both Rails 2.3.4 and 2.3.5.

Answer (score 2):

Actually using the [rails_xss plugin](http://github.com/NZKoz/rails%5Fxss), which was my ultimate goal contains a fix for this.

I just had to change my helper to do this `concat( content.html_safe! )`

Answer (score 2):

since Erubis 2.7.0 you can exploit the :bufvar option in this way:

```
Erubis::Helpers::RailsHelper.init_properties = {:bufvar => '@output_buffer'}
```

Comment: This fixed a problem I was seeing under rails 2.3.14 where I saw the error `undefined method `safe_concat' for nil:NilClass` when calling form_for

Answer (score 1):

Erubis and Rails 2.3 don't work together well. Check out this post: http://daveelkins.com/2009/06/18/making-erubis-264-and-rails-23-work-together/ He has created a gem on github that gets them to work together.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

Erubis::Helpers::RailsHelper.init_properties = {:bufvar => '@output_buffer'}

to config/initializers/erubis.rb fixed it for me